# How to clear an array except first index?

Tags: javascript

Here is my array

```
$scope.colorListArr = [
      {id:-1 , name: "Select Color"},
      {id:1 , name: "1 Color"},
      {id:2 , name: "2 Color"},
      {id:3 , name: "3 Color"}
];
```

I want to remove all elements except first index i.e "Select Color" .

Comment: `arr.length = 1;`.

Comment: @Tushar +1 for this solution, it's the first time I see it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)/[slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to remove/select wanted/unwanted elements.
for more on splice and slice refer MDN

```
 $scope.colorListArr = [{id:-1 , name: "Select Color"},{id:1 , name: "1 Color"},{id:2 , name: "2 Color"},{id:3 , name: "3 Color"}];
 $scope.colorListArr.splice(1,$scope.colorListArr.length);
```

Comment: You should give explanations with your code. It will help the OP and other users to understand why you suggest to use `slice` and how it works.

Comment: You must use `$scope.colorListArr.splice(0,1)`. The slice () method returns a portion of the original array, the portion is defined by a start index and an end index

Answer (score 3):

`$scope.colorListArr.slice(0,1);`

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new array with the first item.

```
arr = [arr[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.colorListArr.length = 1;
```

The [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property of an array isn't just for show. You can set it to a value lower than the current length of the array to truncate the array. You can also set it to a higher value and create empty slots at the end of the array.